# calculate angle for equilibrium

Tags: trigonometry

please see the image below for an understanding of the question

i have found the tension in the string to be 57.5N and the acceleration of the system to be -1.7m/s^2 when the angle is 30deg

coefficient of friction u=0.3

the equations i use are 
T-10gsin30-10gucos30=10a
and
5g-T=5a

The question asks what does the angle need to be to keep the system in equilibrium.
My understanding is the system will be in equlibrium when a=0, however using this and the equations above i cannot get the angle to calculate to 12deg. so could someone please show the workings for this.

thanks,[image]

Comment: This would be more suited for the physics stack exchange [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this belongs here, but I'll still answer. Typically, you first write down Newton's law for each participating body.

Let us denote $m_1=10 \mathrm{kg}$, $m_2=5\mathrm{kg}$, and let the tension in the string be denoted $T$. The string is assumed to be perfect, meaning its not stretchable, breakable and so on. We choose the positive direction to go down the slope, i,e, accelerations down the slope are taken to be positive. Then
$$m_1g \sin\theta -T = m_1a_1\\-m_2g+T=m_2a_2$$ 
Requiring equilibrium means that $a_1=a_2=0$. Then we can simply solve for $\theta$ to obtain:

$$\theta = \arcsin (m_2/m_1)=\arcsin(0.5) = 30^\circ$$.
If anything remained unclear, just ask.